Implication of having a classical oracle separation for $QMA$ and $QCMA$
There is a known quantum oracle relative to which QMA is not contained in the QCMA class. [Aaronson & kuperberg '07]
It is unknown if there exists a classical (deterministic) oracle relative to which one can show the separation between QMA and QCMA.  [see recent paper by Natarajan & Nirkhe '23]
My query:
Apart from being (an elegant) mathematical exercise to find such a classical oracle, will the existence of such (classical) oracle reveal (or imply) something unique about the QMA vs QCMA problem that is not obvious from having a quantum oracle separation?
Note: In the paper (Natarajan & Nirkhe '23), I can't find a conclusive answer to my query. The best I could find is as below (taken from the paper)

... Whereas, the "gold-standard” of oracle separations — namely black box function separations (also known as classical oracle separations) — only requires access to a classical function that can be queried in superposition.


The Aaronson-Kuperberg paper has the related discussion after stating their result in the introduction: quantum oracle separation implies that "quantum nonrelativizing" technique is needed to prove QMA=QCMA (if this is the case). Classical oracle separation removes "quantum" in the implication. According to the paper, there was no known quantum non-relativizing but classically relativizing technique. (I am not aware of any progress in this direction after then.)
